# I am new to python. I tried running a simple while loop but am receiving syntax error

Tags: python, while-loop

I tried running the below code but VS Code is showing syntax error. I checked on internet and notes but found the loop is fine.

i = 1

```
    while i <= 5:

        print(i)

        i = i + 1
```

[While loop showing syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0feR.png)

Comment: The code you showed works perfectly on my computer!

Comment: Nothing to do with the code. It seems you give a bash command to the python interpreter. The `>>>` prefix means you are in the python interpreter, go out of it and run your command, and remove the `&`

Comment: Thanks azro. The code is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code but you should try to create a new folder preferably outside of Appdata. or One drive folder

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with your actual code. When I run it it executes as you would expect. I think the problem must be the way you are executing the program. I think you are attempting to run it in the python interpreter. Where it says "2:Python" you want it to be like "cmd" or "Code" or something and then you can just type in `python loop.py` maybe try clicking the plus next to it or select the first option in the dropdown.